# javascript [object Object] to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'll start with a little background.

So what I'm trying to do is grabbing the "style" attribute from an element, and the eventual plan is to output it to a text box (the styling is dynamic). With this I'm creating some css prefixing, due to the fact that I'm only grabing computed styles.

With that, I have a variable with a bunch of css properties as seen here:

```
compcss = {
                'font-size': fsize,
                'padding': tpadd,

                '-webkit-border-radius': brad,
                '-moz-border-radius': brad,
                '-o-border-radius': brad,
                '-ms-border-radius': brad,
                'border-radius': brad,

                'background': bground,
                'background-m': bgmoz,
                'background-o': bgop,
                'background-i': bgie,
                'color': 'white',
                'text-shadow': '0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
                'text-decoration': 'none',
                'border': '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',

            };
```

Normally fsize, tpadd, brad, and bground are filled with

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(cssStr[0], "")[style]
```

but for the following jsbin I put in static numbers.

This returns as `[object Object]` when logged or put into the text box, which is to be expected. However, I wish to get this object outputting as a string in the form:

```
font-size: Xpx;
padding: Ypx;
-webkit-border-radius: Zpx;
```

and so on, I've tried JSON.stringify(compcss), but that returns as:

```
"font-fize":"Xpx","padding":"Ypx","-webkit-border-radius":"Zpx"
```

all the way down the line.

What is the best way to get this to output the way I want? Let me know if anything needs clarifying. Is there a better way of going about this?

here's a jsbin for example: http://jsbin.com/opiwuy/2/edit

Both Vanilla Javascript and JQuery are fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter if were putting object properties in quotations or not??  Or can we define them with or without?

Comment: @SethenMaleno Not necessary to have any of the properties in quotations, this is to be used in a stylesheet. I've accepted a solution already, but thank you for your interest.

Comment: @MoDoFox I am really asking for my own sake.  I've never seen properties listed in an object with quotations.

Comment: @SethenMaleno You know what... I'm not sure why some of them are returning in "'s

Comment: @MoDoFox You are saying that the properties are returning in ''s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  var value = '';
  $.each(compcss, function(key, val) {
    value += key + ' : ' + val + ';' +'\n';
  });
  $('#css').val(value);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/onovus/4/edit#source)**

You can also do

```
$('#css').val(function() {
    var value = '';
    $.each(compcss, function(key, val) {
      value += key + ' : ' + val + ';' + '\n';
    });
    return value;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/equqet/2/edit#source)**

Comment: I was trying to do similar stuff but this breaks the `color: "white"` as `color: white`. +1 for the effort.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. It seems I have fallen trap to thinking too hard about something that has a fairly simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

something like this would probably suit your needs:

```
function cssStringify(myObject) {
    var result = "";
    var stringObjs = JSON.stringify(myObject).split(",");
    $.each(stringObjs, function(val) {
        var pair = val.split(":");
        result = result + pair[0] + ":" + pair[1] + ";\n";
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing out my version with `.replace`

```
var xx = JSON.stringify(compcss); 
$('#csjson').val(
    xx.replace(/":"|":/g, ":")
      .replace(/,"/g, "\n")
      .replace(/"/g, ""));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/opiwuy/4